# JWT Auth custom user token

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt

I'm using laravel 5 and [JWTauth package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens). I'm wondering if it's possible to use a custom token to authenticate a user. Instead of encoding the user's full details, just  encode id and email.

The reason why I want to do this is because every time the user updates his details, the app needs to generate new token and update the header bearer token. Otherwise the token is invalid. Is there other way/better way to do this?

I would appreciate your recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: You should not be adding all the user's info into the token, only an identifier, which goes in the subject claim.

What code are you using to generate the token ? As my package does this by default

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I do that? I'm using these 2 methods to  generate the user token `JWTAuth::fromUser($user) and JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)`. This returns the user's full details.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the token in this way.

```
$user = User::first();

$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
```

or

```
try {
                //attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
                if(!$userToken = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                    return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
                }
            } catch(JWTException $e) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
            }
```